# BQ40Z80 configuration

Tags: texas-instruments

I have a board battery managment BQ40Z80 Texas Instuments.

At the moment, I can send command to board, can read data from registers.
But... I have a problem too. Now the board flag `OperationStatus[PRES]` is low(0), board flag `ManufacturingStatus[CAL_EN]` is high always, and charge/discharge does not work.

Communication with the board is carried out using an external microcontroller(stm32).

```
----- OperationStatus -----
IATA charge control:              0
Emergency FET shutdown:           0
Cell balancing status:            0
CC measurement in SLEEP mode:     1
ADC measurement in SLEEP mode:    1
SMBLCAL auto cc starts:           1
Initialization after full reset:  1
SLEEP mode triggered via command: 0
400-kHz SMBus mode:               1
Authentication in progress:       0
LED Display:                      0
XCHG Charging disabled:           1
XDSG Discharging disabled:        0
SECURITY mode10-unsealed,01-full: 00
Fuse status:                      0
PDSG Pre-discharge FET active:    0
PCHG Precharge FET active:        0
CHG FET active:                   1
DSG FET active:                   0
PRES System present low:          0
---------------------------
----- ChargingStatus -----
NCT Near charge termination. :   1
CCC Charging loss compensation:  0
VCT Charge termination:          0
SU Suspend charge:               0
IN Charge inhibit:               0
--------------------------
----- Gauge Status -----
DSG Discharge/relax:    0
TC Terminate charge:    0
TD Terminate discharge: 0
FC Fully charged:       0
FD Fully discharged:    0
------------------------
----- BatteryStatus -----
Overcharged Alarm:              1
Terminate Charge Alarm:         1
Overtemperature Alarm:          1
Terminate Discharge Alarm:      0
Remaining Capacity Alarm:       1
Remaining Time Alarm:           0
Initialization:                 1
Discharging or Relax:           0
Fully Charged:                  0
Fully Discharged:               0
Error code 0x0-ok, 0x7-unknown: 1101
-------------------------
----- Manufacturing Status -----
CALIBRATION mode:                             0
LIFETIME SPEED UP mode:                       1
PDSG_EN Pre-discharge FET test:               0
LED display is enabled with the push button.: 0
FUSE_EN Fuse action:                          0
BBR_EN Black box recorder:                    0
Permanent failure:                            0
LF_EN Lifetime data collection:               0
FET_EN All FET action:                        0
GAUGE_EN Gas gauging:                         0
DSG_EN Discharge FET test:                    1
CHG_EN Charge FET test:                       0
PCHG_EN Precharge FET test:                   0
--------------------------------
----- Gpio -----
PIN 22 (LEDCNTLC/GPIO) RL2:                  0
PIN 21 (LECDNTLB/GPIO) RL1:                  0
PIN 20 (LEDCNTLA/PDSG/GPIO) RL0:             0
PIN 17 (PRES/SHUTDN/DISP/GPIO) RH0:          0
PIN 16 (CB7EN/PDSG/GPIO) RH1:                0
PIN 15 (VC7EN/DISP/GPIO) RH2:                0
PIN 13 (DISP/TS4/ADCIN2/GPIO) RC3 or AD3:    0
PIN 12 (V7SENSE/TS3/ADCIN1/GPIO) RC2 or AD2: 0
----------------
Temperature:           20
```

there is log: https://pastebin.com/uruksRFn

Comment: In the BatteryStatus, many alarms and nonzero error code; Are these oh..K? That tells the BQ40 feels the battery was overcharged, and over heated (DANGER!), and terminated/prevented from charging. Does it allow flushing the status to reset?

Comment: Hi, I think this is due to the settings of the board itself and this problem can be solved. But I'm more interested in why PRES bit is low(0), it should to high(1) judging by the documentation

Comment: Could you post a link to the doc., please?

Comment: https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/sluubt5c/sluubt5c.pdf?ts=1629650115399

Comment: PRES pin needs to be configured to be functional. It looks like an input to BQ. Isn't CAL_EN normal, if you need to calibrate it? Without a close look, I cannot tell what you are doing. Data sheet is [here](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/bq40z80)

Comment: @jay i found a bug in my program, everything is fine now, the question can be closed

Comment: thanks for the help!

Comment: Good work kotC9!